# JDK issue, terminal won't recognize commands (javac, javah ect) when JDK is installed.

Tags: command-line, jdk, netbeans

Hi I installed JDK alongside Netbeans 8.0.1 and all the java commands are found in: /home/username/jdk1.8.0_31/bin and it's not recognized in the terminal when I type javac, javah ect. Can someone show me how I can edit the path so I can use these in the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in ~/.bashrc add something like

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/username/jdk1.8.0_31/bin
```

and logoff/logon (or simpler

```
. .bashrc
```

Sometimes it's usefull too to set JAVA_HOME to /home/username/jdk1.8.0_31/ path